# How to append dynamic text to url in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, url-rewriting

I have a html form which method type is post, now i want to append text to my website url in PHP. The text changes dynamically.

**current url :**

```
www.example.com/index.php
```

**expected url :**

```
www.example.com/index.php/hotels-in-bangalore
```

(or)

```
www.example.com/index.php?qry=hotels-in-bangalore
```

I just want to append text, other than that every thing should remain same. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your HTML form code, so that we can get an idea of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure why you try to accomplish, but here are few solutions:

put url in form action:

```
<form action="index.php?qry=hotels-in-bangalore" method="post">
```

or you can do it in php

```
if (!empty($_POST['name']) {//put some logic here
  header("Location: index.php?qry=hotels-in-bangalore");
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript if you want to redirect to correct page after submitting immediately.

So it will be something like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="tbSearch" id="tbSearch" />
  <input type="submit" id="submitSearch" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#submitSearch").click(function() {
   window.location.href="index.php?qry=" + encodeURIComponent($("#tbSearch").val());
});
</script>
```